# Prompt doesn't update git branch

Tags: bash, git, bashrc

I tried to integrate the current git branch in my prompt, but it doesn't behave as expected. I'm using bash on ubuntu 16.04 and git 2.7.4.
When I start a terminal nothing of git is shown. If I source my `.bashrc` from inside a repository the branch is shown, but doesn't update anymore. This is what I wrote in my .bashrc:

```
green="\[\033[01;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[01;34m\]"
no_color="\[\033[00m\]"
purple="\[\033[01;35m\]"

source ~/.git-prompt.sh
export PS1="$purple\u $green$(__git_ps1 " (%s)") $blue\W $no_color \$ "
```

#### Update:

I tried follow the instructions in [git-prompt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) but still the same result. However if I just copy the suggestion from git-prompt: `PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '` it works, but of course doesn't look like I want. Is there some syntax error I'm missing? 
The template PS1 works even if don't use export, just `PS1=...`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. It is not necessary to use prompt command. The bug arises due to a syntax error.

If I assign the content of PS1 with `""` in order to use my variables for the colors, it only executes the __git_ps1 function when `.bashrc` is sourced.

But when I assign the PS1 content within `''` and do it without variables for the color and instead write the codes out, it works as expected. And as I read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247585/to-export-or-not-to-export-bash-ps1-variable) it seems to be better practice not to export PS1 to the environment.

So the solution looks like:

```
PS1='\[\033[01;35m\]\u \[\033[01;32m\]$(__git_ps1 " (%s)") \[\033[01;34m\]\W \[\033[00m\] \$ '
```

However I would be curious to know, what's the reason for this. It works within `""` in macOS.

Comment: It does work, thanks. However it's a pain in the neck when you have the colors set as variables.

Comment: glad it works for you. However, in the meantime I switched the shell to zsh. zsh in combination with oh-my-zshell is just so much nicer and more convenient. I'd recommend to use zsh and choose a theme for the shell prompt you like.

Comment: weird. just surrounding it in single quotes instead of double quotes seems to fix it

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same problem. You can simply escape the `$(...)` to `\$(...)`

```
export PS1="$purple\u $green\$(__git_ps1 " (%s)") $blue\W $no_color \$ "
```

Comment: Agreed. There's a deeper explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5380073/135101.

Comment: THis was the issue, thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's because `.bashrc` is read only once: when you start a new interactive non-login shell (when you open a new terminal, for example). So the `PS1` is set the first time you open the terminal and is never changed.

The right way of doing this (assuming your `git-prompt` and `__git_ps` scripts work as expected) is to use `PROMPT_COMMAND`. As explained in `man bash`:

```
   PROMPT_COMMAND
          If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each
          primary prompt.
```

You want `__git_ps1` to be run before each prompt is shown (so after every command you run; after a `cd`, for instance). Therefore, you need to put it into `PROMPT_COMMAND`. If your `__git_ps1` is what I think it is, it will be setting `PS1` for you. You just need to run it each time a prompt is shown. So, add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="$purple\u $green$(__git_ps1 "(%s)") $blue\W $no_color \$ "
```

Finally, I can't be sure since you're not showing the relevant scripts, but I very much doubt that the `(%s)` makes sense there. That will just print the string `%s`. If you need more help, please edit your question and i) include both `__git_ps1` and `/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt` (or tell us how you installed them if they came from an Ubuntu package) and ii) show us what your prompt is supposed to look like.

Comment: I updated my question. I know that `.bashrc` is only read once, but nonetheless the prompt should update every time.

Comment: @Pepe it won't unless you use `PROMP_COMMAND` as I explain in my answer. Did you try it?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but you're on the wrong track. Also the %s is not needless. I posted the solution below.